# How can I share a cell value between two Excel documents?

Tags: excel

I have two documents that should share a numeric value that should also increase by one after each time one of the documents are used.

For example:

- I open docA.xls and it should say 001.
- I'd like to be able to change it to 002 and save.
- When I open docB.xls, it should say 002, because docA's value is 002.

I'm pretty sure I can create a third spreadsheet that I could update to update the two cell values, but I'm wondering if there is a way to link cells other

1. than having a formula that reads `=A1`.
2. I realize I could have one workbook with three spreadsheets, as well.

But what is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: If you have two documents then why would (2) be an option?

Comment: @brettdj This question is almost a year old.  I acknowledged in (2) that I could have multiple workbooks or multiple spreadsheets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One workbook w/ 3 spreadsheets would be the most straight-forward; you can specify which spreadsheet in a cell reference, so both sheets could explicitly refer to the same cell.  And if you don't like explicitly using the row/col reference, you could always assign it a name and use that.

Answer (score 5):

Copy the first cell.
Paste on the another sheet as a Paste Special => Paste Link.